# OLEDB SQL Syntax Error, I can't see it

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledbconnection

I am trying to send a new user on my C# program to the database (MSAccess in this case). I create the string as follows...

```
String StrCmd = String.Format("INSERT INTO tbl_Users (Username, Password, IsAdmin) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', {2});", Username, passwordHash, AdminPower);
```

This creates an SQL string, for example...

```
INSERT INTO tbl_Users (Username, Password, IsAdmin) 
VALUES ('TestUser', '1013638657', False);
```

This works fine if I paste it into a Query in MSAccess, but in the code I keep getting a `Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.` error.

Can anyone see something obvious I am missing?

Additional Information:

`Username` and `passwordHash` are Strings, `AdminPower` is a Boolean.

`Username` and `Password` are Text Fields, `IsAdmin` is a Yes/No Field.

Code Block of interest...

```
OleDbConnection MyConn = new OleDbConnection(Program.ConnStr);
MyConn.Open();
String StrCmd = String.Format("INSERT INTO tbl_Users (Username, Password, IsAdmin) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', {2});", Username, passwordHash, AdminPower);
OleDbCommand Cmd = new OleDbCommand(StrCmd, MyConn);
Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MyConn.Close();
```

Comment: String.Format() is **not** an acceptable way to substitute values into an sql query. It's still crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks, I already considered this, but other than that I clean the strings before passing them to the SQL, quite frankly if Admins of the program which will be sitting on their on their own laptops decide to break into the database, they don't need an sql injection attack to do it, they can just open the database file that's sitting in the same directory. ;)

Comment: That's no excuse not to do it right... cleaning strings is not correct. Quarantining them is. Always use parameterized queries.

Comment: Please explain about `IsAdmin` field. Is it boolean type(true/false) or string type("Yes"/"No")

Answer (score 0):

try this `'{2}'`:

```
String StrCmd = String.Format("INSERT INTO tbl_Users (Username, Password, IsAdmin) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}');", Username, passwordHash, AdminPower);
```

Comment: Already did, makes no difference. :( Still get the same error

Comment: @StephenHammond, can you try this: `String StrCmd = String.Format("INSERT INTO tbl_Users (Username, Password, IsAdmin) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', {2});", Username, passwordHash, 0);`

Comment: Thanks for the help. Solved it.. *mutters about stupid SQL having different reserved words in different platforms... mutter*

Answer (score 0):

*Facepalms* I noticed the the list of reserved words I was checking was for SQL-Sever. I found one for MSAccess and "PASSWORD" is a reserved word in Access... I changed it to UserPassword, and it works...

grrr.